# how to use read bash builtin to read sever's answer from hose client (netpipes)

Tags: bash

doing `hose localhost 22 --in sh -c "cat"` works well. Openssh answers:

SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3

but trying `hose localhost 22 --in sh -c "read var; echo $var"` doesn't work. var is null, why? Then how to read server's answer line-by-line in bash? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because $var gets interpreted in the executing shell already, where it is probably unset.

You want

```
hose localhost 22 --in sh -c "read var; echo \$var"
```

or

```
hose localhost 22 --in sh -c 'read var; echo $var'
```